# Trying to down a connection using nmcli and the connection says unknown?

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to create a bridge connection but when I run the connection during the process

```
$nmcli conn down eno1np0
```

I get the message

```
Error: 'eno1np0' is not an active connection.
Error: no active connection provided.
```

but when I run

```
$nmcli conn show --active
```

I get the following below so it is definitely there

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE     >
Wired connection 1  ************************************  ethernet  eno1np0    >
Wired connection 3  ************************************  ethernet  enp72s0f3u1>
virbr0              ************************************  bridge    virbr0
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

This is on Centos 8.

Comment: What does it show as in nmtui, and what happens when you try to deactivate it in nmtui?

Comment: You cannot `down` a device, only `disconnect` it. The connection name is `Wired connection 1`.

Comment: it shows in nmtui and when I deactivate it, of course i lose internet, and then reactivating brings my internet back up but I still get the same message when trying to down the connection through nmcli with it giving me a "not an active connection" message

Comment: ahh ok, I'm entering the name under device but not the name itself which is 'Wired connection 1'. I'm able to run the command now. Got mixed up because the tutorial I was following had both name and device as the same.